# How to get the service UUID of a Bluetooth device using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I need to connect to a Bluetooth device and get the battery level of it using Python? I was able to connect to it, but I need the service UUID of the Bluetooth device I need to connect. How to get the service UUID used for battery level and other things and How to use the UUID to get the corresponding output.

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

async def main():
address = "CB:07:9F:D6:58:BD"

Connect to the Bluetooth device
async with BleakClient(address) as client:
Read, write, or do something with the connection
>         ...
print(client.is_connected) # prints True or False

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Does this help? https://getwavecake.com/blog/reading-your-phones-battery-level-over-bluetooth-ble-with-python-bleak/

Comment: @PeterHenry Thank you for the response link. It works.